# 3 searchbox with 3 question marks, Sikuli Fails to click 2nd element

Tags: selenium, sikuli

I have 3 search box field and 3 question marks near by each search box. If I try to click on the 2nd question mark, It always clicks the 2nd Search box instead of clicking the question mark button. **[Sikuli not clicking the exact element]**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfmyD.png) Kindly have a look into the below image i have attached. Click "[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfmyD.png)" to view the image... Pls dont come up with coordinates. I shouldn't use coordinates in my project.

Comment: If you are using selenium, why worrying for Sikuli to find similar elements. Is it a web application's modal dialog you are handling?

Comment: Please post relevant code. With the information provided now, it is very difficult to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Yea Its a modal dialog box, if its a alert or child window i can easily automate. When i had an walk-through with the developers they told me like its devloped by ShowModalDialogBox(arg1, arg2, arg3). If there is anyother way to handle ModalDialog boxes in selenium pls do let me know. But make sure we dont use AutoIT, Robot class and Corodinates.

Comment: @Striker: I am not supposed to post my code here :'( really sorry :(

Comment: @mk08 : ?? Is there any other method ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be the fully qualified answer, which do not use Region, Co-ordinates & autoIT as you are expecting.

This is code in Sikuli which uses `findAll()` method.

I created a dummy window as per your screenshot as below:
[image]

**Edit**

```
public void clickButton() throws AWTException, FindFailed
{
    m_sikscr=new SikuliScript();
    m_screen=new Screen();
    m_sikscr.switchApp("Java Swing Examples");
    m_screen.wait((double)3.0);
    int i=0;
    Match[] array=new Match[5];
    Iterator<Match> rs1 = m_screen.findAll(new Pattern("./img/Button1.png"));
    while(rs1.hasNext())
    {
        array[i]=rs1.next();
        i++;
    }

    m_screen.click(array[1]);
            
}
```

This clicks only the second button on screen.

Hope this much triggers the thought of making it work completely.

Comment: Hi really thanks for the example code. But the thing is here am using it in while loop, so it is just sending "text" to all the text boxes and clicking all the buttons. but my motto is to click on only 2nd question mark button

Comment: Thanks a lot :) will try it and revert back to you :)